# How to implement TCP connection handshaking with Spring Integration?

Tags: java, tcp, deserialization, spring-integration, handshaking

I'm new to Spring Integration and currently trying to receive data from some devices over TCP.
I've come up with the following Spring context:

```
<bean id="serializer" class="com.somepackage.CustomSerializer"/>

<int-ip:tcp-connection-factory id="connectionFactory"
                               type="server"
                               port="${tcp.socket.connection.listener.port}"
                               deserializer="serializer" />
```

The problem with a device's protocol is that upon initial connection it sends a handshaking sequence and expects a magic answer before it starts sending the **messages**.

A **message** pattern is different from the handshaking sequence, I cannot implement a serializer that distinguish between these two. If I could I would implement this handshaking process as an interceptor. 
So I tried to implement a statefull serializer but it turned out that serializers are singletons, shared between different connections.

Could you please advise how to perform some custom negotiation (handshaking) before default mechanisms (splitting data into messages) come into play ? Should I customize a connection factory ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a custom [TCP Interceptor](http://static.springsource.org/spring-integration/reference/htmlsingle/#ip-interceptors). From the documentation:

> 16.4 TCP Connection Interceptors
>
> Connection factories can be configured with a reference to a TcpConnectionInterceptorFactoryChain. Interceptors can be used to add behavior to connections, such as negotiation, security, and other setup. No interceptors are currently provided by the framework but, for an example, see the InterceptedSharedConnectionTests in the source repository.

Comment: Yes, I tried but an interceptor relies on already parsed input stream onMessage(Message<?> message), and my deserializer does not know how to parse an input stream because it has no state

Comment: See the websocket stuff in the extensions repo - it uses a stateful deserializer together with an interceptor. https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-integration-extensions/tree/master/spring-integration-ip-extensions However, it needs Spring Integration 3.0 so the interceptor can get access to the deserializer's state (and clean it up when the connection is closed).

Comment: Ok so since Spring Integration 3.0 is not released yet I've followed the approach of customizing connection factory and implemented a handshaking logic in a place where new connection is created.